# Como pegar JSON de uma URL pra usar no meu arquivo PHP?

Tags: php, json

Quero pegar o valor do dólar do JSON exibido nessa URL:

http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json

pra usar no meu arquivo php, tem como fazer isso somente com PHP?

Também tem essa opção XML:

http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=xml

Comment: Queria pegar só esse valor do dólar sem usar mais nada além do php, mas se não der, pode me mostrar como fazer com jquery se puder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com:

```
file_get_contents('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json');
```

Não dá, porque esse url está a bloquear por `user_agent` mas nós podemos falsea-lo. Tenta assim:

```
function get_page($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

// true como segundo parametro do json_decode, signica que queremos os que vá buscar os conteudos como array em vez de ser como objeto, retire o true se quiser ir busca-los como objeto
$contents = json_decode(get_page('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json'), true);
print_r($contents);  // Array ( [status] => 1 [valores] => Array ( [USD] => Array ( [nome] => DÃ³lar [valor] => 3.5969 [ultima_consulta] => 1464713701 [fonte] => UOL Economia - http://economia.uol.com.br/ ) ) )
```

Comment: Assim funcionou @Miguel, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @RaylanSoares

Comment: Só uma nota, `file_get_contents` suporta sim manipulação da requisição para usar os headers, como user-agent, no caso um exemplo: `$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1\r\n" )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json', false, $context);`, se puder atualizar a resposta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu sei, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192669/5749 , mas na altura não tinha os recursos para testar con file get contents e por isso só apresentei com curl

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é verdade, mas nem me lembrava desta

Answer (score 0):

use esta função

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context [, int $offset = 0 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )


<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.testmagazine.com/test.php?type=menu";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Outro exemplo:

```
$url = "http://link/data.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $resp;exit;
```

Comment: Não entendi como funciona, até tentei substituir a URL pela que eu vou usar mas não funcionou. Poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: faça só assim para teste $response = file_get_contents("http://seulink");
print_r($response);