# Como copiar tudo de um site e guardar num arquivo txt

Tags: php

Bom, o que pretendo fazer é relativamente simples:

Pretendo copiar o código todo deste link:

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198337627631/inventory/json/730/2/

E guardar num arquivo txt.

Como poderei fazer isso com PHP?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer com curl assim:

```
<?php
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198337627631/inventory/json/730/2/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MOZILLA YOOO');
$page = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$f_handler = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($f_handler, $page);
```

E com file_get_contents:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozzila yooo\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$page = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198337627631/inventory/json/730/2/', false, $context);
$f_handler = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($f_handler, $page);
```

Comment: Miguel, com o file get contents, não está a funcionar.

Comment: Que erro te dá?

Comment: Simplesmente, não escreve nada.

Comment: E o curl escreve?

Comment: Também não, não está a escrever.

Comment: Tens a visualização dos erros ativa? o que me dá às vezes é o error 429: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes , que são demasiados request do mesmo cliente. Experimenta mudar o url, ou aguarda uns minutos